# How to find core test names to generate specific tests

Tags: magento2, testing, mftf

I am trying to run MFTF tests only for Checkout.

In the DevDocs there are various examples how to generate and run specific tests([MFTF - Getting started - Step 4 - Run a simple test](https://devdocs.magento.com/mftf/docs/getting-started.html#run-tests), [Generate tests by test name](https://devdocs.magento.com/mftf/docs/commands/mftf.html#generate-tests-by-test-name), [Generate and run particular tests](https://devdocs.magento.com/mftf/docs/commands/mftf.html#generate-and-run-particular-tests)).

I've had a look at the [MFTF action group reference](https://devdocs.magento.com/mftf/docs/actiongroup-list.html) but it seems like these are not the test names required to generate and run specific tests.

**Where can I find these test names?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Test names can be found in the tests xmls inside the modules `Test/Mftf/Test` directory.

Here an example *vendor/magento/module-checkout/Test/Mftf/Test/StorefrontVerifySecureURLRedirectCheckoutTest.xml*:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
 /**
  * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
  * See COPYING.txt for license details.
  */
-->

<tests xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:mftf:Test/etc/testSchema.xsd">
    <test name="StorefrontVerifySecureURLRedirectCheckout">
        <annotations>
            <features value="Checkout"/>
            <stories value="Storefront Secure URLs"/>
            <title value="Verify Secure URLs For Storefront Checkout Pages"/>
            <description value="Verify that the Secure URL configuration applies to the Checkout pages on the Storefront"/>
            <severity value="MAJOR"/>
            <testCaseId value="MC-15531"/>
            <group value="checkout"/>
            <group value="configuration"/>
            <group value="secure_storefront_url"/>
        </annotations>
        <before>
            <createData entity="_defaultCategory" stepKey="category"/>
            <createData entity="_defaultProduct" stepKey="product">
                <requiredEntity createDataKey="category"/>
            </createData>
            <amOnPage url="{{StorefrontCategoryPage.url($$category.name$$)}}" stepKey="goToCategoryPage"/>
            <waitForPageLoad stepKey="waitForPageLoad"/>
            <moveMouseOver selector="{{StorefrontCategoryMainSection.ProductItemInfo}}" stepKey="moveMouseOverProduct"/>
            <click selector="{{StorefrontCategoryMainSection.AddToCartBtn}}" stepKey="clickAddToCartButton"/>
            <waitForPageLoad stepKey="waitForAddToCart"/>
            <waitForElementVisible selector="{{StorefrontCategoryMainSection.SuccessMsg}}" time="30" stepKey="waitForAddedToCartSuccessMessage"/>
            <see selector="{{StorefrontCategoryMainSection.SuccessMsg}}" userInput="You added $$product.name$$ to your shopping cart." stepKey="seeAddedToCartSuccessMessage"/>
            <see selector="{{StorefrontMinicartSection.quantity}}" userInput="1" stepKey="seeCartQuantity"/>
            <executeJS function="return window.location.host" stepKey="hostname"/>
            <magentoCLI command="config:set web/secure/base_url https://{$hostname}/" stepKey="setSecureBaseURL"/>
            <magentoCLI command="config:set web/secure/use_in_frontend 1" stepKey="useSecureURLsOnStorefront"/>
            <magentoCLI command="cache:flush" stepKey="flushCache"/>
        </before>
        <after>
            <magentoCLI command="config:set web/secure/use_in_frontend 0" stepKey="dontUseSecureURLsOnStorefront"/>
            <magentoCLI command="cache:flush" stepKey="flushCache"/>
            <deleteData createDataKey="product" stepKey="deleteProduct"/>
            <deleteData createDataKey="category" stepKey="deleteCategory"/>
        </after>
        <executeJS function="return window.location.host" stepKey="hostname"/>
        <amOnUrl url="http://{$hostname}/checkout" stepKey="goToUnsecureCheckoutURL"/>
        <seeCurrentUrlEquals url="https://{$hostname}/checkout" stepKey="seeSecureCheckoutURL"/>
        <amOnUrl url="http://{$hostname}/checkout/sidebar" stepKey="goToUnsecureCheckoutSidebarURL"/>
        <seeCurrentUrlEquals url="http://{$hostname}/checkout/sidebar" stepKey="seeUnsecureCheckoutSidebarURL"/>
    </test>
</tests>
```

Within the `<tests>` node the `name` attribute describes the tests name and the `<group>` nodes describe the groups this test is associated with.